# Programming languages like C#, Go, Rust, Scala get rewritten to itself, doesn't it make them too slow?

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, programming-languages, compiler-optimization, interpreter

I am writing an interpreter for a dynamic language just for fun. And I sometimes take a look how some features are implemented in other compilers.

While it is not that bad for Rust or Haskell to be rewritten to itself, I can imagine how slow the others may become. Especially those which have GC like Golang.

I understand all the proc like fast development and so on..

#### But is such a heavy performance hit worth it?

Comment: Note that all the languages you listed are compiled (C# and Scala target VMs, but those VMs certainly aren't written in C# or Scala). The language a compiler is written in won't affect the speed of the compiled code. All it can affect is how long the compilation itself takes, but the choice of programming language is usually not the bottleneck when it comes to compilation speed.

Comment: You're right in assuming that GC in most cases is pointless for a compiler, as compilers do not live long enough to accumulate too much garbage. A region allocator nuking everything from the past passes is a better approach. But it's not such a huge performance hit either.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with performance issues on C#. I reviewed source code of some core methods including GC. Sometimes parts of this code is written on C++ sometimes on Assembler.  I do not think that it will be possible to achieve the same performance using clear C#.